# tsc CLI not reading the types in the right way

Tags: typescript

Here's the code:

```
interface Interval {
    start: Date | number
    end: Date | number
}

function getOverlappingDaysInIntervals(
    dirtyIntervalLeft: Interval,
    dirtyIntervalRight: Interval
): string {
    const intervalLeft = dirtyIntervalLeft || {};
    const intervalRight = dirtyIntervalRight || {};
    const leftStartTime = intervalLeft.start;
    const leftEndTime = intervalLeft.end;
    const rightStartTime = intervalRight.start;
    const rightEndTime = intervalRight.end;

    return 'any';
}
```

The code hasn't any errors I tested on the `TypeScript TS PlayGround` site and also `VSCode` doesn't give me any errors.

The problem when I try to check for errors by using this command:

```
npx tsc --noEmit (file path)
```

I got these errors:

```
error TS2339: Property 'start' does not exist on type '{}'.
error TS2339: Property 'end' does not exist on type '{}'.
error TS2339: Property 'start' does not exist on type '{}'.
error TS2339: Property 'end' does not exist on type '{}'
```

What's the difference? Why the `tsc` can't read the types?

NOTE: Even if I change the code to something like this `intervalLeft?.start` I got the same errors.

Comment: the type for `intervalLeft` could just be `{}` - i would just use `intervalLeft?.start;`

Comment: @DanielA.White why it could be {} as I understand it's required I choose the interface keys to be required not optional!

Comment: @DanielA.White Also why does just the tsc CLI give me these errors?

Comment: different options/versions. etc. you coalesce optionally on `{}`  on those lines so its possible `intervalLeft` or `intervalRight` don't conform to the `IntervalType` anymore

Comment: @DanielA.White Hmm I know understand thank you, the Last question are there any specific options for this case?

Comment: @DanielA.White Sorry but even after using intervalLeft?.start I got the same errors!!

Comment: Remove the || part